# dreamweaver and zend2 errors

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dreamweaver

I've been using Dreamweaver version 11.0 to construct a dynamic website using php and ZF1.  I just started to migrate to ZF2 and my code is working but I'm getting red "syntax errors" for any line that has "\" such as:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
```

Is there anyway to tell Dreamweaver not to view this as an error?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest moving to another IDE such as Zend Studio. Dreamweaver is more inclined towards front-end development technologies. Also Zend Studio has lots of integrated libraries, including Zend Framework and lots others.

If your project is complex you can use both Zend Studio and Dreamweaver, just create a site in Dreamweaver and add all html content directories such as public, layouts, views to this site and you will be able to change your html here....

Comment: @Eric check out Eclipse. It's free and Zend Studio is a commercial version of it.

Comment: Fantastic!  I'll take a look; you've potentially saved me a couple of hundred bucks.